# Value not copied into the correct Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple sheets in the same workbook, and I'm trying to copy certain cell from sheet 1, 2, & etc. and paste into a column G on sheet "Claim".

Sheet 1, 2, &x have the same format.

When copying over, I'd like to paste from the first empty cell up to the count of total records from sheet 1/2/x.

The problems are

1. The value pasted onto Column keep getting overridden when handling multiple sheets.
2. The copied from value - I only need a component of the same cell, but not sure how to achieve that. e.g., MID(Cell,5,11)

sheet 1, 2 &x are protected sheets which I import from elsewhere and I don't really want to write

```
Sub AddClaimRef()
Dim nrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long


'Add Claim Reference
For x = 1 To Sheets.Count
If Worksheets(x).Range("A2").Value = "STORE NAME:" Then
Worksheets(x).Select
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Cells(1, 9).Copy


Worksheets("Claim").Select
nrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
Range(Cells(nrow + 1, 7), Cells(Lastrow - 9, 7)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
Next


End Sub
```

Expected Result -

1. Mid(Cell(1,9),5,11) get copied from sheet 1 - x, but I don't know how to do that.I was only able to copy cell(1,9)
2. If sheet 1 has 100 records with cell value 
   "SHEET1", sheet 2 has 200 records with cell value "SHEET2"
   I'd expect Column G to populate value "SHEET1" from Row 2 to Row 101 and
   populate "SHEET2" from Row 102 to 302

But the actual output is that Row 2 to Row 101 gets overridden by value "SHEET2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [NO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) `.Select` and [NO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) `.Activate` and [NO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) `.ActiveSheet`
2. Declare all of your variables (`x`) and qualify all of your ranges `[What Sheet?].Cells(.....`
3. You need to calculate the last row on your paste sheet as this changes with each loop
4. This is set to copy from `Range("I9")` on each sheet you loop through
5. This is set to paste on `Last Row + 1` on `Column G` and will repeat the value as determined by `ws.Column A`
6. Indenting your code properly makes the loops and steps much easier to follow/debug/update in future

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Update()

Dim Claim As Worksheet: Set Claim = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Claim")
Dim ws As Worksheet, LRp As Long, LRc As Long

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> Claim.Name Then
        If ws.Range("A2") = "STORE NAME:" Then

            LRc = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            LRp = Claim.Range("G" & Claim.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            Claim.Range(Claim.Cells(LRp, 7), Claim.Cells(LRp + LRc - 1, 7)).Value = Mid(ws.Range("I9"), 5, 11)

        End If
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```